# How to add $ symbol to the value field in the pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have field which is taking string as datatype and that field has values like $20000 and `N/A`. I am using the string as datatype I want to show data like this $20000 and `N/A`, but I am getting it as a 20000 and `N/A`. How can  I get data  as  $20000 and `N/A`. I am using that expression:

```
=IF([annual_roll_amount]=="N/A";"N/A";"$" &[annual_roll_amount])
```

What is wrong in this expression and Is it ok to use that in value field under attributes??

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is wrong.
you have to use CONCATENATION.

```
=IF([annual_roll_amount]=="N/A";"N/A";CONCATENATE("$";[annual_roll_amount]))
```