# How to format currency in string field in pentaho designer

Tags: pentaho

I have this formula in value of text element. how can I format the amount to format this $#,##0

=IF([amount]=0;"N/A" ;"$"+[amount])
I want the amount should be formatted in report. how can i change the expression to get that.

Comment: possible duplicate, delete the post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527899/how-to-add-symbol-to-the-value-field-in-the-pentaho-reporting-designer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add $ symbol to the value field in the pentaho reporting designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527899/how-to-add-symbol-to-the-value-field-in-the-pentaho-reporting-designer)